# Any Advantage to Giving All Collections a Separate Root Node in XML Documents?

Tags: xml

I haven't worked with XML files all that much. But I'm writing an app now that saves its data in XML format.

So far, I've come up with the following basic structure.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<categories>
  <category id="cf6cb6bc-8142-4366-9b43-0ae6fce90df2">
    <subcategories>
      <subcategory id="02b95e55-a4f7-4979-b0aa-a97f2c3327b0">
        <articles>
          <article ... />
          <article ... />
        </articles>
      </subcategory>
      <subcategory id="5e9f9ef7-5190-4bcd-ab98-935d9208a4c7">
        <articles>
          <article ... />
          <article ... />
        </articles>
      </subcategory>
      <subcategory id="7077d614-d3de-42d3-851a-b8c9ce0f56df">
        <articles>
          <article ... />
          <article ... />
        </articles>
      </subcategory>
    </subcategories>
  </category>
</categories>
```

But after looking at it, it seems like there are some unnecessary elements here, and that the same data could be shortened to the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<categories>
  <category id="cf6cb6bc-8142-4366-9b43-0ae6fce90df2">
    <subcategory id="02b95e55-a4f7-4979-b0aa-a97f2c3327b0">
      <article ... />
      <article ... />
    </subcategory>
    <subcategory id="5e9f9ef7-5190-4bcd-ab98-935d9208a4c7">
      <article ... />
      <article ... />
    </subcategory>
    <subcategory id="7077d614-d3de-42d3-851a-b8c9ce0f56df">
      <article ... />
      <article ... />
    </subcategory>
  </category>
</categories>
```

It seems the file as a whole requires a root node. However, it doesn't appear all subcategories and articles also need a dedicated root nodes. So my shortened version just dumps all the subcategories directly under the category tag, and all the articles directly under the subcategory tag.

Could someone who works more with XML files tell me if there's any reason at all not to use the shortened version above.

Comment: As long as your document is valid XML document I don't think you need to have 'dedicated root nodes'.  XML documents are already verbose, so keeping it as short as possible should be better.

Comment: Neither do I. But I just wondered if there was any disadvantage to not having them.

Comment: The only disadvantage is if `<category>` nodes had other stuff at the same level as the `<subcategory>` nodes in your abbreviated sample.  Then it might be useful to group all the subcategories under their own `<subcategories>` node.

Comment: Good point @JimGarrison. Mixing it with other data might not be as clean. In my case, there are no other child elements.

Comment: The latter form is a less direct mapping to the data structure you're serialising. This can be interpreted as both bad - (slightly) more cognitive burden when coding the serialisation code; and good - it's a more "XML" design, and if you're documenting / validating with XSD you get rid of a mostly superfluous element definition. Practically speaking I don't think there's any hard rules on which you should choose - XML binding libraries expect to have to deal with the latter scenario, etc.

Comment: Personally, even when mixing it with other data, I'd choose the latter. It gets rid of a level of nesting, and in XSD you can easily forbid interleaving the different child elements of `subcategory`. (You can *maybe*, and less easily, allow the order in which sequences of identical elements appear to be flexible. E.g. allow `<a><b/><b/><c/><c/></a>` and `<a><c/><c/><b/><b/></a>` but disallow `<a><b/><c/><b/><c/></a>` - but I'm not 100% sure XSD can do this.) This should make even mixed data appear clean since continuous blocks of  lines starting with `<article ...>` are visually distinctive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see no reason to have the extra hierarchy, if there is only one per parent node and they have no attributes or special data of their own. I would just have `subcategory` directly under `category` and `article` directly under `subcategory`. I personally like to keep things clean and simple  :)

EDIT:
I agree with @JimGarrison, if you had other data at that level, which from your example you don't seem to have, then grouping them under one node would have had an advantage.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes accurate data modelling demands the extra level. For example if you want attributes on "articles" to indicate the range of dates to which the articles apply, then it might be inappropriate to make these attributes of the subcategory element, especially if a subcategory might contain either articles or books with different attributes in each case.

The wrapper elements for containers or collections can also make programming easier if the container has siblings of a different type: for example if a book has a title, a publisher, and several authors, then wrapping the authors in a container element can make things clearer.

But in general I'm for avoiding clutter in the data model; get rid of excess layers that serve no useful practical purpose.